# Guide to choose which is the best for VM - microsoft or vmware

Tags: email, exchange, virtual-machines, sql, virtualization

i am confused between VM Ware and Microsoft Hyper V whic one is the best in terms of all. is there any comparison chart then please let me know.

as to run os in vmware need to install esxi; it is same in the microsoft to run hyper v.

as i want to create microsoft sql 2013 server and ms mail exchange server.

Thanks.

Dharam

Comment: As you want to run Microsoft Packages, I'd say Hyper-V. If you had Linux software VMWare would likely be slightly better. The question is, how much do you have to spend?

Comment: You talking about running a full VM virtualisation platform on a server, or just having some VM's running in your workstation?

Comment: As it stands, I think this is not a suitable question for this site though. Imho it's a "list of best..." with no 'right' answer.

Comment: There is no best overall.  Both excel at some things and struggle at others.  Both have very different licensing schemes.  You have to see which best meets you needs for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The [virtualizationmatrix](http://www.virtualizationmatrix.com/) web can provide some insight into various hypervisors features and their comparison. I use it for answering such generic customer's questions.

Comment: This is *awesome*.

Comment: Yep, for customers especially :-) and for sysadmins as well if you don't have time to check regularly what's new in the latest versions of hypervisors.